# Offline Flyback DC-DC converter using NE555, Works in LTSpice, will it work in a real world application?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, 555

I'm currently a novice and am learning EE. I've been experimenting with low voltage DC-DC converters. Now I want to build an offline DC-DC converter that operates directly from AC mains.

The schematic works very well in simulation, but being this converter draws its power directly from AC mains, I'd like some input from experienced users/professionals before I build this thing and test it in a real world scenario.

**This NE555 circuit is only a learning tool. The objective was to take on a project way beyond the scope of my knowledge and I decided to build a SMPS using basic oscillators and designing all of the auxiliary circuitry around them.**

**I'm aware of the existence of and have many different SMPS control ICs.**

**Update**

I took the entire circuit apart and rearranged it a bit. I realized in order for PFC to really work the transformer has to be wound for the max voltage, so I'm operating the boost converter from a pre-regulator then once the boosted output hits 360VDC it starts up the flyback circuit. Once the flyback's regulated output reaches 14.8V it shuts the pre regulator off. All occurring within a half a second or so.

Will the pre-regulator blow up? I know I'll survive up to 170VDC I've tried these (get very hot after a few minutes, but will power an NE555 and a few transistors), but at 340VDC? I know the jump from 340 to 360 won't take more than 60ms, could be safe, but What do you guys think?

**Here's are the latest revisions
The output results are with PFC output @ 360VDC carrying a 129Ω load (>1KW)**

**Schematic**
[image: More Organized]
**First is both the boost converter and transformer waveforms without current traces.**
**Second is Boost converter only with current trace.** 
**Third is transformer only with current trace**
[image: OutPuts]

Comment: I'm an experienced EE, I design circuits for a living. **Low voltage circuits**, including DCDC converters. Could I design a mains powered DCDC converter ? Probably. Would I do it ? Nope. Why not ? Because it will not bring anything compared to an off-the-shelf module. Also there are lots of practical issues, like **electrocution risk** being one of them. Also your circuit looks overcomplicated. Why use the 555 ? There are special purpose ICs for this.

Comment: There is a difference between making something working in a simulator and the real world. For example, in the simulator things do not blow up. I see a transformer there but it's not for **isolation** ? Oh, you're switching the high voltage directly to low voltage. Hmm, everyone else uses a **transformer** for this (flyback converter). Can you guess **why**. There are 2 important reasons. Why have you chosen a different topology ? Even if it worked I would not use your converter to charge my phone, can you guess **why** ?

Comment: I did add the transformer for isolation. The only un isolated connection goes through a 100K resistor to charge the capacitor so that once it's reached a charge of 12V it dumps out to the NE555 starting up the transformer and continuing to power the circuit via the transformer.    That transformer is just to power the primary chips, I wouldn't use it to charge a phone either.   I used the NE555's and OpAmp because I don't have the models for the SMPS controller chips I have.

Comment: I suggest that you study how mains supplies are build up because yours uses the same ground everywhere and your ground is mains referenced via the bridge rectifier. So your design is **not** isolated. If it was you'd be able to draw a line between input and output without crossing any connections. Usually this line will go through the transformer, opto coupler (for feedback) and a Y-rated capacitor. Despite what you say this circuit is **not** isolated.

Comment: In case you are planning to make youtube videos about your circuits: do it as a live show. Dead people can't upload stuff.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I'm curious as to where the errors are in my circuit? I know things turn out different in simulation than the real world (I've blown up quite a few components), which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: All in all: as a theoretical exercise, learning how to use a simulator, this design is OK-ish. But I would not show it as an example to aspiring DCDC converter designers. And I would not build it.

Comment: It is not that there are "some errors" in your circuit which you can "fix" and all will be well. You will need to take a step back, look at how commercial power adapters are build up (use Google Image search for "flyback converter circuit") and try to understand **what** is done for safety and isolation and **why** that is done. Another good sources are EEVBlog and Bigclive on Youtube, they take power supplies apart and comment on the design and implementation.

Comment: Oh, just found this: http://micro.rohm.com/en/techweb/knowledge/acdc/acdc_pwm/acdc_pwm01/889/  It might help you learn the how and what about isolation etc.  As far as I know Linear technology has some models for their power converter ICs and you can simulate these in LTSpice.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I have looked up commercial flyback supplies, maybe I missed something, but I thought the control chips were grounded to the main rectifier. I planned to add galvanic Isolation to the rectified output of second transformer I plan to add to the circuit, which is what will actually power the load.

Comment: *the control chips were grounded to the main rectifier* and they are. But note that that "ground" is just the ground reference of the primary side, it is not connected to mains earth (mains must remain isolated from earth !) but it is also not (directly) connected to the output ground. The output ground **can** be connected to mains earth, if possible I'd even recommend that as it makes the output safe to touch. There is more than one ground and they should not be connected !

Comment: Look at this: http://micro.rohm.com/en/techweb/upload/2016/04/4A_ckt_whole-1024x645.gif  and notice how the grounds are truly separated except for the X-rated capacitor C10 (usually 1 nF).

Comment: @FakeMoustache Oh I know Earth is a totally different point of reference. This circuit is ONLY to power the primary. I know I have to ground the Load transformer to the chassis, filter the mains input for switching noise, add caps, etc. I kept it simple because when I add the SG3525 It slows the simulation down to a near halt, so I don't even get to test the high/low side driver.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Any better?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Yeah and I like to touch live exposed 120vRMS mains lines with my bare wet (a little salt helps) hands too! Especially Live in my right hand, Neutral in my left while standing barefoot on PE! It's QUITE the experience! I really like it at high frequencies for that exfoliating effect! Who needs laser skin treatments when you have skin effect, right?

Comment: @user14828 you might want to check this out if your having solver issues http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Convergence_problems%3F (if you haven't seen it already)

Comment: @laptop2d Thanks for that, I hadn't even realized I was having convergence issues. I'm new to EE & since reading that last night, I've vastly improved the design of the signal clipper for the soft start.

Comment: There are two solvers for LTspice one works better for DC to DC applications

Comment: @laptop2d  I don't know what the solvers are,can you explan? I'm no engineer yet. I'm a programmer. I put these circuits together logically. You know, a circuit is like a program the current has it's origin and end like code. Each component is a function. On the simplest level an AND gate is like a CMP on 2 bits. I only know how to use this program to build AC circuits. I just learned how to change the trace colors the other day, lol.

Comment: @user14828 Google LT spice solvers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NE555 is IMO totally unsuitable for such a design as the pulse width of the first pulse is invariably much longer than any subsequent pulses. This is due to the fact that the timing capacitor is charged and discharged between 1/3 and 2/3 of the supply ...except for the first time you charge it, and you always start from zero charge on the capacitor. So the first pulse is from 0 - 2/3.
This makes soft start almost impossible to engineer, and can result in large initial currents since you don't know when in the AC cycle you will first make contact.

I see no attempt here to make the supply zero crossing startup and your (I assume an attempt) at soft start looks quite flawed. Particularly the drive for Q1, Q7 and the fact that the C8 charge dump is not AC synchronized.
The first pulse from U1 will be much longer because of the ramp on C5 continuously raising the C6 aiming voltage and the complications with exactly what voltage it will get to. When your charge dump (Q1/Q2) turns on there is uncontrolled discharge of C8 through Q1/Q2 which I don't think you intended.

If I were to test this I'd be using a transformer as isolation and start with perhaps a 50 V RMS output.

Additional Comments 4/22 circuit:

1. Pre-Reg shutdown. Overcurrent base drive from Q31 driving Q30. Need a base resistor.
2. Pre-Regulator. Do you really need 9900 uF capacitance?
   Need a 270 Ohm resistor between C9 and Q3 Collector pulldown to lower Q3 current discharging C9.
3. Zero-Crossing. Do you really need Pre_Charge since it's derived from Pre_Supply?
4. PFC-Startup Controller and Flyback Startup-Controller. Need base resistor in Q2/4. Consider when latch turns on the base current is limited only by Q18/20 Beta.
5. PFC Softstart and Transformer Softstart. Clamping U2_out and U4_out appears faulty. You are trying to hold the amplitude of the signal low, but with insufficient current limiting.
6. Positive voltage regulator. If I read correctly Pre_Charge will be about 17-18 V, so Positive_Voltage will not turn on. The voltage for the two BE's, 3 diodes and a zener come to about 20 V, but if Supply goes over 20 V then there is an uncontrolled current path. Perhaps you could remove a diode and replace with a resistor and still get the correct operation.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you mentioned the charge dump because the control chip's aren't really my issue. I have SG3225s, FAN4800s, Hi/Low side MOSFET drivers, etc., that I would use in the design of a power supply that had a purpose other than experimentation. The purpose for this experiment is the charge dump. I've been trying to make a low voltage regulated supply for the primary side of an offline DC-DC converter.  It made sense to me to feed C8 through R2 then once C8's charge exceeds 12V it will cause D7 to conduct in the opposite direction, applying current to the base of Q2, pulling down the

Comment: ..base of Q1, dumping C8's entire charge into the NE555 driver circuit (D16 prevents feedback into D7) which starts switching M1, charging L3, inducing current in L1, feeding the driver circuit. There was no attempt at a soft start (didn't know I needed that in a flyback, if I do then I stand corrected). I really didn't think the first pulse being longer was going to be an issue because I've read that actual control chips vary duty cycle and if you look at the values of R14 and R15, the NE555 is switching at a pretty low duty cycle. I'm very new to EE so I'm sure there are mistakes.

Comment: The waveforms look good though. The peak voltage between L3 and M1 are >200V over supply which at peak is 595V (I have 800V MOSFETS). But correct me where I'm wrong I've only done this particular one simulation.

Comment: I've made changes to the circuit, do you think it's any better? I think I added a soft start.

Comment: Your charge dump Q1/Q2 appears to work better now, though I have to say that using zeners directly feeding a transistor base makes it very difficult to predict turn on voltages with any accuracy.

Comment: Thank you, you've been very helpful. I've actually modified the schematic further, where I'm getting a more gradual startup on the transformer, decreasing the Ipeak to >7A, but the boost circuit exceeds 50A which I'm guessing isn't good. How would you handle the transistor timing? Voltage divider?

Comment: The boost surge could be controlled by reducing the BR output capacitance and a PTC resistor I guess, though it would be nice to have some logic at play instead.   For the charge dump what you really want is logic again.  ...(If V > 16V and ZeroCrossing=True then trigger switch)..... This would get your FET switch triggers aligned with a low voltage on the output of the BR when you start up.

Comment: I've made some changes to my schematic. Even if I start up at zeroCrossing, If I startup without some kind of gradual increase I get nasty peaks in M2 and that's with no load except the little transformer running it all. I do have some heavy duty FCH072N60s (and even better ones) that can handle 52A continuous and 156A pulsed, but isn't there a way to time the voltage increase at the gates better than the way I'm doing it? Will that even work in reality?

Comment: I've made further amendments to my circuit(posted above), I can't say starting up at zeroCrossing did too much however the soft start was the ticket to keeping currents low. I didn't find it difficult to engineer soft start, however a perfectly linear startup has been quite the caveat but that may be due to my scope of knowledge. I appreciate your input. I learned a lot from it, thank you. However at this time I do not agree that the NE555 is totally unsuitable for such a design as long as the necessary auxiliary circuitry is incorporated into the design.

Comment: You've made significant changes, and certainly improved your design overall. Glad I could help in some way. I do still think that using the 555 has resulted in some odd design elements, especially with low current base protections for example. I'm surprised that zero crossing alignment didn't help control startup currents more. I'm stunned how good the waveform simulations turned out.

Comment: zeroCrossing did reduce current peaks by between 20-50A(still too high though) on the boost circuit, depending on load, so overall you were correct about startup at zeroCrossing, but I really saw the effect in the transformer. I learned to control the PWM with the inverted AC pulse based on that which will be very useful in the future. You did also teach me that driving transistor bases from  the back end of a zener wasn't a great Idea (now I think it was ridiculous lol), so you've helped A LOT more than you think. So do you think it'll work in real life? I'm kinda not trusting my soft start.

Comment: You know I've just realized you've beyond answered my question. If the waveforms look good it should be good.

Comment: Good luck with it. Given the restriction to use the 555 you've actually turned out a great design. Not many would have persevered ...I certainly would not have. Congratulations on getting a working simulation for such a complex design.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment (I read your profile, you know your stuff). You certainly provided me with the correct information which got me there. I just hope it works as well when I build it, lol.

Comment: You were correct again! I sharpened the startup by adding a smaller cap at SUPPLY then start switching at the FETs threshold voltage (4.5v) and BINGO! current spikes dropped by 6A,(21A). I also removed the second push pull amp as it was unnecessary, and added a small resistor in parallel with a diode. I'm getting much better performance, I'll post an update as soon as I'm done improving the soft start.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the schematic again and letting me know what you think. It should be much easier to read as I broke it into modules. I think I got a pretty good soft start, but for some reason when I try to drive the transformer from a push-pull amp and the waveform floats as if it isn't properly sinking, it worked on the boost but I cut it from both of em to lower the part count and TBH the waveforms look better without the amps. I't still floats a bit off of 0v(transformer) but not enough to turn the FET on.

Comment: I totally forgot the base resistors on Q2, Q4 & Q30 when I redid it. #3 Zero_Crossing does require a direct tap from the pre regulator or there won't be a Zero_Crossing signal to meet the conditions of the PFC Startup. #5 The soft start circuit works great with increased impedance and a push-pull amp for the PFC but there's a sinking problem with the transformer switching signal. I figured the wave clipper biased with the transistors as a voltage source #6 I looked at the circuit again and I'm working voltage issues. I think most are worked out at this point. Thank you, I appreciate it.